# SSLHandshakeException при отправке POST запроса с помощью JSOUP

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Есть код который отправляет пост запрос на сервер

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://mysite.com")
                            .data("first", "true")
                            .post();
                    Log.d("tag", doc.body().text());
```

Возникает такая ошибка:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:381)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:209)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:478)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:165)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:746)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:722)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:306)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.post(HttpConnection.java:301)
        at ru.kiceargy.rcr$1.run(remote_controller.java:31)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:276)
        at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:197)
        at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:584)
        at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
06-20 18:48:17.387 27351-27366/ru.kiceargy.rc W/System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:378)
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        ... 18 more
```

Гуглил долго, решения так и не нашел.

Comment: ну так сертификат на https://mysite.com по всей видимости самоподписанный

Answer (score 0):

причина в защищенном соединении, не все версии андроида справляются с этим, к примеру 4.1 не может зайти со стандартного браузера на git, решением будет

```
.validateTLSCertificates(false)
```

попробуйте так

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://mysite.com")
                        .validateTLSCertificates(false)
                        .data("first", "true")
                        .ignoreContentType(true)
                        .post();
                Log.d("tag", doc.body().text());
```